# Overloading the + operator

Tags: c++

```
string operator + (const string &s, char *lit);

string operator + (const string &s, char *lit)
{
    string temp;
    temp.len = s.len+strlen(lit);
    temp.str = new char[temp.len+1];
    strcpy(temp.str, s.str);
    strcat(tmep.str, lit);
    return temp;
}
```

This is what my proffessor gave me as sample code as an example for overloading the string class. Thing is, when I compile it it says

```
std::string operator+(const string&, char*)’ must take either zero or one argument
```

I'm just wondering why it's not compiling? It'll take just one arg. but won't take two. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your actual program (the relevant parts please).

Comment: Technically, this should compile since it isn't even being used yet. I just put the prototype in the header, and the code in the .cpp file.

Comment: This should take a `const char *`, not `char *`, anyway.

Comment: @mwerschy, I'm not creating it, I'm overloading it for that class. And I'm pretty sure + exists as an operator.

Comment: @chris char * is a const, because we're not modifying it, just getting the strlen and copying it.

Comment: It can't take two arguments though... And where did my comment go?

Comment: Your question excludes critical information. A static or non-member `operator+` can take two arguments. Your question doesn't indicate in any way that `operator+` is defined as a member function.

Comment: @SieuPhan, But if I run it in C++11 and give it `str + "hello"`, it will fail to compile. You need to assure the compiler you're not changing it so that it can enforce that. I'd recommend changing this to implement it in terms of `operator+=` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your professor meant namespace scope function (just usual function).

And you happened to declare non-static member function instead (I guess within some class named "blog").

operator+ accepts 1 or 2 arguments *in namespace scope* (binary operator+ accepts 2 arguments and unary operator+ accepts 1 argument) but as a *non-static member function* (in class scope) it accepts 0 or 1 argument (because it already has first implicit argument defined by **this** pointer).

Comment: I just removed it from the class blog for simplicity purposes.